# Como usar as funções filter_?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tento utilizar as funções `filter_` (`all`, `at`, `if`), mas sem sucesso, principalmente para strings. Considere o conjunto de dados abaixo:

```
set.seed(1234)

data_1 <- data.frame(
  a = c(paste('group', 1:6, sep = '_')), 
  b = c(paste('new', 1:6, sep = '_')), 
  d = c(rnorm(6, 10, 1))
)
```

Perguntas:

- Como filtrar, **de uma só vez**, tudo que contenha a partícula `1`? (`filter_all`)
- Como filtrar, **de uma só vez**, tudo que contém `1` e `3` nas variáveis `a` e `b`? (`filter_at`)
- Como filtrar, **de uma só vez**, tudo que contém `1` e `3` nas variáveis `a` e `b` e, tudo que for maior (`>`) que `10` na variável `d`? (`filter_at`)
- Como filtrar tudo aquilo que é `character`, se ela conter as partículas `1` e `3`? (`filter_if`)

Pequeno esboço do que tentei:

```
library(dplyr)

filter_at(data_1, c('a', 'b'), any_vars('1'))
```

> Error: No tidyselect variables were registered

Tentei filtrar as variáveis `a` e `b`, mas não deu certo.

Nunca usei a função `filter` com estes sufixos, por isso a dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar vou refazer os dados com `set.seed` para tornar os resultados reprodutíveis e com o argumento `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, para responder à última questão.

```
set.seed(1234)

data_1 <- data.frame(
  a = c(paste('group', 1:6, sep = '_')), 
  b = c(paste('new', 1:6, sep = '_')), 
  d = c(rnorm(6, 10, 1)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Quanto às questões, vou também fazer uma pequena alteração em relação à maneira como tentou resolver os problemas, vou usar os *pipes* `%>%`.

Comum a todos os problemas vai ser a utilização de `grepl`, uma vez que as colunas `a` e `b` são de classe `"character"`.

**1.**
Aparentemente mais fácil. Mas não é completamente claro se pretende só as linhas onde ocorre  `'1'` em *todas* elas ou em *alguma* delas.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_1 %>%
   filter_all(all_vars(grepl('1', .)))
#        a     b        d
#1 group_1 new_1 8.792934

data_1 %>%
   filter_all(any_vars(grepl('1', .)))
#        a     b         d
#1 group_1 new_1  8.792934
#2 group_2 new_2 10.277429
#3 group_3 new_3 11.084441
#4 group_5 new_5 10.429125
#5 group_6 new_6 10.506056
```

**2.**
Esta pergunta é mais simples. Resolve-se com `grepl` aplicado ao pronome `'.'`.

```
data_1 %>%
  filter_at(vars(a, b), any_vars(grepl('1|3', .)))
#        a     b         d
#1 group_1 new_1  8.792934
#2 group_3 new_3 11.084441
```

**3.**
Agora vai ser uma condição lógica composta.

```
data_1 %>%
  filter_at(vars(a, b, d), 
            all_vars(grepl('1|3', a) & grepl('1|3', b) & d > 10))
#        a     b        d
#1 group_3 new_3 11.08444
```

**4.**
Finalmente o `filter_if`. Aqui também se põe o problema de poder ser `all_vars` ou `any_vars`. Por acaso os resultados são iguais.

```
data_1 %>%
   filter_if(~ is.character(.), all_vars(grepl('1', .)))
#        a     b        d
#1 group_1 new_1 8.792934

data_1 %>%
   filter_if(~ is.character(.), any_vars(grepl('1', .)))
#        a     b        d
#1 group_1 new_1 8.792934
```

Comment: Ótimo. Obrigado, Rui.